# Husqvana YTA 22V46 Belt keeps getting loose

Tags: belt, tractor, husqvarna

For some reason i bought the belt for this tractor from the manufacturer, but when i disengage the blades, the belt gets super loose almost completely off. I went to home depot to get a 42" and a 46". The 46" was the exact same size as the current one so i didn't even bother trying it on and the 42" was too tight.

I followed the diagram for the belt just fine, it just comes off every single time. Any fix for this? Or has anyone come across an issue like this with any tractor?

Comment: There will be belt adjustment. Look and adjust.

Comment: @SolarMike I mean i have looked around to make sure i didn't miss any latches or something and it looks fine. its pretty straight forward. anything special to keep an eye out for?